# Free PDF writer for Windows 8 Metro Apps

Tags: windows-8, pdf-generation

Is there any PDF writer for Windows 8 / Metro Application? I am developing a Windows 8 App and looking for a library that can generate PDF documents programmatically which can be used to print or email.

Comment: Take a look at Siberix PDF Sparkle (free for use in commercial projects) or Siberix Report Writer (http://www.siberix.com). Both products have Windows Store (WinRT) editions.

Answer (score 1):

[iTextSharp](http://sourceforge.net/projects/itextsharp/) is a C# port of a Java library called [iText](http://itextpdf.com/index.php). Most of the updated documentation you'll find on the web will be in Java, but the [API](http://api.itextpdf.com/itext/) remains basically the same.

See this [Hello World](http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=12) example. Many others can be found [here](http://itextpdf.com/book/examples.php) (or you can browse them sorted by [keyword](http://itextpdf.com/themes/keywords.php)).

**EDIT** : it looks like some dependencies can't be fullfilled in the Metro env, so iTextSharp won't be a solution.

Comment: Don't forget that iTextSharp is AGPL-licensed. I.e. either pay for license or open-source your solution.

Comment: @Bobrovsky That's correct, but since the OP didn't mention any particular license (apart from *Free*, which could be interpreted in various ways)... Also note that pre-5.x versions were under LGPL/MPL. It's highly discouraged to use these versions though. See [a comment](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12384410/1065525) from the main author of iText(Sharp) regarding this topic.

Comment: @AlexisPigeon, I tried using iTextSharp in my metro app but it requires reference for System.Drawing which is not available in Windows 8 Apps.

Comment: Oops, my bad. Feel free to downvote my answer then...

Comment: I have added all the dll's required for iTestSharp in my metro app but it says Could not load file or assembly 'System.Drawing', Please help me out how can i resolve this ???????????

Comment: I have added all the dll's required for iTestSharp in my metro app but it says Could not load file or assembly 'System.Drawing', Please help me out how can i resolve this ??????????? Have any one got luck on this @devson

Comment: @user1516781 Read the full answer: iTextSharp **CAN NOT** be used inside Metro apps.

Comment: First of all thanks for the answer , Is there any other alternative which i can use ? , Please let me know , Thanks in advance.

Comment: @user1516781 If I knew any, be assured I would have posted it here...